# Interfaces / Classes / Objects and Inheritance

Tags: vb.net, oop, object, inheritance, interface

I'm trying to rebuild some old QBASIC (yeah, you read that right) programs for use on more modern systems (because for some reason kids these days don't like DOS).

I understand the basic principles of classes and objects (I think) but I'm obviously missing something.

I have a number of instruments which are controlled using GPIB, using VISA COM libraries. I can make it work, but the code is very ugly :(

In order to use an instrument, I have the following in my Public Class Main:

```
Public ioMgr As Ivi.Visa.Interop.ResourceManager
Dim myInstrument As New Ivi.Visa.Interop.FormattedIO488
Dim myInstOpen As Boolean
```

Then, when I come to initializing the instrument (in the 'Initialize' button click sub), I use:

```
Try
    myInstrument.IO = ioMgr.Open("GPIB0::17")
Catch exOpen As System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
    myInstOpen = False
End Try
```

Pretty straightforward stuff; if the instrument can't be opened at address 17 on GPIB0, it throws an exception, which gets caught and sets the 'myInstOpen' flag to false.

Then, I can communicate with the instrument using commands from the Ivi.Visa.Interop.FormattedIO488 interface such as:

```
myInstrument.IO.ReadSTB()
result = myInstrument.ReadString()
myInstrument.WriteString("GPIB Command Here")
```

And all of it works.

What I want to do is, create a generic 'Instrument' class, that allows me access to all the functions from the Ivi.Visa.Interop.FormattedIO488 interface, and from the Ivi.Visa.Interop.ResourceManager interface, but also allows me to build my own class.

For instance:

```
Public Class GPIBInst
Implements Ivi.Visa.Interop.FormattedIO488
  Public Address As Integer
    Public Sub setAddress(ByVal Addr As Integer)
        Address = Addr
    End Sub
    Public Function getAddress() As Integer
        Return Address
    End Function
    Public Function readIO() As String
        Dim Data As String = me.ReadString()
        Dim Result As String = mid(Data,2,7)
        Return Result
    End Function
End Class
```

This would allow me to use the functions from the interface, but also customize the instruments for other useful things inside the program. For instance, the GPIBInst.Address needs to be used in other places, and the GPIBInst.readIO() can be used instead of just the generic ReadString() so that I can customize the output a little.

**BUT** when I try to do this, I can't *inherit* from the interface (because it's an interface) and I can't *implement* the interface because it says my class needs to implement every single function which the interface provides. I don't want all these functions, and also, I can't work out how to write them all into my class anyway (they have heaps of random stuff in them which I don't understand lol).

If anyone can see where I'm coming from and can offer some advice, I'd really appreciate it =)

Comment: When you say you "can't implement the interface", which interface do you mean? Is there another implementation of this interface that you want to add functionality to, or are you implementing the interface yourself for the first time?

Comment: Hi David, I mean the Ivi.Visa.Interop.FormattedIO488 interface.

I can implement the interface in this manner:
Dim myInstrument As New Ivi.Visa.Interop.FormattedIO488

But then I can't add additional properties to it such as address

Comment: And when I use
Public Class GPIBInst
Implements Ivi.Visa.Interop.FormattedIO488
It asks me to implement every function from the interface =(

Answer (score 0):

An interface is supposed to represent a coherent set of functionality; implementing part of it but not all of it violates the intent of the concept. That being said, it is very common for APIs in object-oriented languages that wrap non-OO systems to just define one massive interface rather than breaking the functionality into logical sub-groups and defining an interface for each group. If that is your circumstance, and you want to implement the interface, you have no choice but to implement every method from the interface (although you can throw a NotImplementException for any method that you don't want to fully implement, as long as that will not prevent your class from functioning properly).

Comment: "wrap non-OO systems to just define one massive interface rather than breaking the functionality into logical sub-groups"

This seems to be exactly what they've done here with the library they've provided.

Is there an easy way to partially implement the methods / functions I don't need? For instance:

Class 'Instrument' must implement 'Sub WriteList(ByRef data As Object, [type As IEEEASCIIType = IEEEASCIIType.ASCIIType_Any], [listSeperator As String = ","], [flushAndEND As Boolean = True])' for interface 'Ivi.Visa.Interop.IFormattedIO488'.

Comment: Do I have to write an entire:

Sub WriteList(ByRef data As Object, [type As IEEEASCIIType = IEEEASCIIType.ASCIIType_Any], [listSeperator As String = ","], [flushAndEND As Boolean = True]) Implements Ivi.Visa.Interop.FormattedIO488.WriteList

And then somehow declare it so that it can't be generally accessed within the class (in case someone uses a function in the interface which I haven't fully implemented)?